# how to save a shape in an image file format with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

So, im starting to learn opengl, i drew some shapes now i want to save it, i found this code in a doc, but im dont see how would i get it to work with my code.
this is my code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void display(void) {

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

  glVertex2f(0.1, 0.1);
  glVertex2f(0.3, 0.1);

  glVertex2f(0.2, 0.3);

  glEnd();

  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

  glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

  glVertex2f(0.3, -0.1);
  glVertex2f(0.3, 0.1);
  glVertex2f(0.1, 0.1);
  glVertex2f(0.1, -0.1);

  glEnd();

  glFlush();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
  glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
  glutInitWindowSize(920, 920);
  glutCreateWindow("First Raster Shape");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMainLoop();


  return 0;
}
```

and the code i found and the docs:

```
void savePPM(int start_x,int start_y,int w,int h,char *fname)
{
        FILE *f=fopen(fname,"wb");
        if (!f) return;
        std::vector<unsigned char> out(3*w*h);
        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT,1); /* byte aligned output */
        glReadPixels(start_x,start_y,w,h, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&out[0]);
        fprintf(f,"P6\n%d %d\n255\n",w,h);
        for (int y=0;y<h;y++) { /* flip image bottom-to-top on output */
                fwrite(&out[3*(h-1-y)*w],1,3*w,f);
        }
        fclose(f);
}
```

the code saves into the ppm format, which im cool with it, but still i want to know how would i make it work with my code. or is there any other way to do it?
link for the docs:
https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2010/spring/cs481/section/2/lecture/03_30_imagefiles.html

Comment: `savePPM(0, 0, 920, 920, "/path/to/yourfile.ppm");`? -- just a wild stab in the dark. Maybe take a step back and read up on how to write and call functions in C++.

Comment: calling the function isn't the issue. the issue is how would i get the values like, the width, height, x, y  from the shapes. since the "display" function doesnt return anything, even if it did, all it has is just vertex and now the data to save it into a file format. i want to know how would i get these data and save it into a image file format

Comment: @Stoicism Do you want the whole window to be in the picture?

Comment: @Stoicism the `display` function does not do anything in image space at all. It's operating in the world space that you set up in `main`. My point about calling the function being an issue was related to your original example showing the function prototype for `savePPM` inside `main` which suggested to me you were having trouble with the basics. If your glut calls do not specify the actual GL viewport size, then you can retrieve the actual sizes from GL: `GLint vp[4]; glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, vp);` - see [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml)

Answer (score 1):

Use a library to write the data to an image file. An option is to use the [STB](https://github.com/nothings/stb). STB is a headers only, single file library. All you have to do is include the header file and you don't need to worry about linking. Use the functions `stbi_write_bmp`, `stbi_write_png` or `stbi_write_tga` to write the pixel data to an image file. e.g.:

```cpp
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION 
#include <stb_image_write.h>
```

```cpp
int w = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
int h = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
std::vector<unsigned char> out(3*w*h);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); 
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, out.data());
stbi_write_png("myfile.png", w, h, 3, out.data());
```